# Ubuntu freezes in Ryzen 3000 and X570

Tags: freeze

Good morning, I have an AMD Ryzen 7 3700x in a motherboard Gigabyte x570 ud v1.0 with Nvidia GTX 1660 Super.
I'm triying to run Ubuntu but there is a lot of freeze problems, during the installation and also when I achieve to install, during the normal use, the SO Ubuntu get freeze randomly. I tried to install another Ubuntu versions like 19.10, 18.04.4 LTS, 16.04, all these with the same problem.
The BIOS is updated to the last version and that doesn't resolve the problem, I have disabled de c-state in the BIOS with the same result.

I tried a lot of times with diferents Ubuntu versions with kernel 5.3 and before but the problem is not resolved.

Someone know what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The real problem is the WIFI PCI-E adapter, is an ASUS RTL8821ae board, for now I'm using ethernet cable but I would like to know why this adapter freeze the SO.

Comment: Could also be a swapfile size issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have the same kind of issues as yours, with the same CPU, and just find this thread which might be handy to you:
[freezes problems](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245608)

Apparently, there are some issues with power management regarding ubuntu 18.04 and Ryzen CPU.

To solve it, try passing `processor.max_cstate=5 rcu_nocbs=0-11` when loading your kernel at boot.
To see how to pass options to your kernel at boot, see: 
[kernelbootparameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Finally I found and fix the problem, was the WIFI PCI-E board installed in my computer.
Also I update the drivers and I have installed the version 440 of Nvidia that add support to GTX 1660 Super.

Comment: I will try to enable the cstate in the BIOS to show if it's a part of the problem, if the problem appear I will try your solution.
Thanks!